# Full Text Search by prefixed FORMSOF result

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is there a way to concatenate a prefix onto all the results of a `FORMSOF()` lookup when doing a `CONTAINSTABLE()` query?  I work in the nordic ski industry, and we sell "rollerskis" for summer training.  As this is a pretty obscure word, the parser doesn't quite give me the right inflectional forms I'd like.  Specifically, if I try to run a `FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"rollerski")`, the parsing function `sys.dm_fts_parser` returns the following terms (no thesaurus, English language):

```
{"rollerski", "rollerskiing", "rollerskies", "rollerskied"}
```

That's close to what I need, but it's notably missing the pluralized **rollerskis**, which is used throughout our website, most notably in the name of several products and product categories. What I would like to do to get a more accurate list is return all the inflectional forms of "ski" and prefix each of them with "roller".  That would give me the following list of terms:

```
{"rollerski", "rollerskis'", "rollerskis","rollerskiing","rollerskies","rollerskied","rollerski's"}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this within the `CONTAINSTABLE()` query?

Comment: How about modifying the [thesaurus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx) instead?

Comment: I looked into the thesaurus, but if possible I'd like to keep the behavior within the database itself or the queries. From my understanding, the thesaurus is tied to the sql instance, which means if I need to move the database to another server, there's a chance the thesaurus file could be forgotten.